# Select everything that comes after a newline

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, substring

I would like to select in a field everything that comes after the line break.

Example in:

```
"Number of implants
Number of SC implants"
```

keep only "Number of SC implants"

Knowing that there is a "\n" between "Number of implants" and "Number of SC implants".

Comment: SQL Server 2012 ran completely out of support last year, @PapaYatmaDiop , you really should be looking to upgrade. Also, however, you should certain be updating your instance; you haven't installed a *single* patch or security update since 2013-01-03; that's *over* a decade ago... When using (completely) unsupported software you *need* to denote that in your question; ideally using the tags.

Comment: Hello @Thom A, thank you for this information, unfortunately I do not have my hands on it. I have only received the accesses to this database and need to extract some information from it.

Comment: Oof, I really suggest you speak to whomever is "responsible" for that instance then, as quite frankly they have been very *irresponsible*.

Comment: Also, your title says PostgeSQL? Which are you *really* using?

Comment: You can use SELECT SUBSTRING(yourString, CHARINDEX(CHAR(10), yourString) + 1, 99999) FROM yourtable; this till find the newline character and then take rest of the string after it

Comment: Indeed @Thom, I will speak to him about it. I don't think they make an effort in this sense since they just use it as a test base

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    SUBSTRING(your_field, CHARINDEX(CHAR(10), your_field) + 1, LEN(your_field)) AS result
FROM
    your_table
```

Comment: Thank @Matt you for this proposal, I forgot to specify that the field in question is of type "text" therefore the LEN() function does not pass, I have the error "SQL Error [8116] [S0001]: Argument data type text is invalid for argument 1 of len function."

Thank you for this proposal, I forgot to specify that the field in question is of type "text" therefore the LEN() function does not pass, I have the error "SQL Error [8116] [S0001]: Argument data type text is invalid for argument 1 of len function."
siggemannen's proposal in the comments goes well.